# Why is the torus not a boundary of a 3-chain?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm learning about homology right now and the author simply states that the torus $T^2$ does not have a boundary (I understand this) and also is not a boundary of a 3-chain. This is not at all obvious to me. So why is this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the author is referring to the torus as an abstract manifold all on its own --- not as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example.  If you think about a simplicial (or cellular, CW, etc) structure on the torus, it wouldn't contain any 3-simplices, so you it certainly wouldn't be the boundary of a 3-chain.  Looked at as a submanifold of another space, however, it may very well be a boundary.